# Why is my .android folder not automatically generating the adbkey and other files? (ADB)

Tags: android, ubuntu, command-line, raspberry-pi, adb

I am trying to use adb on my Raspberry Pi, but my `.android` folder is empty (`ls` shows that there is nothing inside the folder).

I have been trying to find a solution for several days now, and have found that my `.android` folder is completely empty, even though it is supposed to contain the following files:

`adbkey` `adbkey.pub` `androidwin.cfg` `avd` `cache` `repositories.cfg` `sites-settings.cf`

As a result of my `.android` folder being empty, I get the following error whenever I try to use `adb start-server` (or any other adb command):

`* daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
ADB server didn't ACK
Full server startup long: /tmp/adb.1000.log
Server had pid: 2036
--- adb starting (pid 2036) ---
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57] Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5~18.04
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57] Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57]
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57] adb_auth_init
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57] User key '/home/username/.android/adbkey' does not exist...
adb I 05-18 12:15:21 2036 2036 main.cpp:57] generate_key (/home/username/.android/adbkey)...
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon`

The daemon refuses to start because the `adbkey` file (and others listed above)within the `.android` folder do not get automatically generated as they should.

How can I fix this issue? I have tried every solution I could find on Stack forums, but nothing seems to work. I suspect that it has something to do with the permissions of my `.android` folder, but I am not sure what exactly I need to change. I have tried rebooting my Raspberry Pi several times. I am extremely stuck and would greatly appreciate any help I could get.

Answer (score 1):

**Preface: I am not directly experienced with Raspbian, but I have worked with Debian on ARM for some time.**

It seems like this is a historical issue with how `adb` was built for Debian Buster on ARM devices. If you run `adb keygen keyfile.pub` you should most likely see report the message:  `Bus error`. It seems that an out of date library was used to build the version used for the `armhf` architecture. 
[This post on ODROID explains the situation a bit further.](https://forum.odroid.com/viewtopic.php?t=36404)

So, how do we resolve this? From what I can tell, there is no newer version of `adb` in the testing or unstable repos. You have 3 solutions: use a package outside of your distribution, compile yours from source from the package, or use an older version of `adb`. Here, I will recommend to go with the latter.

[Solution adapted from an issue on another ARM port of debian](https://github.com/SolidHal/PrawnOS/issues/143)

To fix it, add stretch as a source in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (via [Raspbian documentation](https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianRepository))

`# deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian stretch main`

then downgrade adb:

```
# apt update
# apt install adb=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-libadb=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-libbase=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-liblog=1:7.0.0+r33-1 android-libcutils=1:7.0.0+r33-1
```

This should resolve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall the current version (1:8.1.xxxx) of the below listed packages and install the older version should solve the issue.

sudo apt install adb=1:7.0.0+r33-2 android-libadb=1:7.0.0+r33-2 android-libbase=1:7.0.0+r33-2 android-liblog=1:7.0.0+r33-2 android-libcutils=1:7.0.0+r33-2